# long long int array pointers arithmetics of this array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem with below code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        unsigned long long int i,j;
        unsigned long long int *Array;

        i=j=0;
        Array=(unsigned long long int*)malloc(18446744073709551616);

        for(i=0ULL;i<18446744073709551616;i++)
                *(Array+i)=i;
        std::cin>>j;
        std::cout<<*(Array+j);
        return 0;
}
```

My compiler (Borland C++ builder 6.0) gives me an Access Violation Error. There are also warnings on the stage of compiling the program. I have never used `unsigned long long int`, so I have no idea where is the problem in this case.

Comment: Why do you need to allocate 18446744073709551616 bytes? That's more than 18k petabytes...

Comment: check the value of `Array` after the call to `malloc`; I suspect it to be `NULL` as I don't think that your system can allocate that amount of memory.

Comment: This is the max value of unsigned long long int

Comment: The next error would be that you have to divide your allocated size by the size of an unsigned long long

Comment: @gonskabalbinka, the theoretical maximum amount of memory that a desktop computer program can use these days is 140737488355328 bytes, which is more or less 100,000 smaller than the max value of unsigned long long int. Do you know how much RAM your computer has? I suspect that it's another 10,000 times smaller than the theoretical maximum...

Comment: It's fine system can not allocate the memory

Comment: Why is Borland C++ involved at all in this in any capacity? What's the motivation behind using that historical relic? This code is just plain strange. How many eternities are you prepared to wait for that loop to finish? At a billion writes per second that will take **five hundred and eighty for years** to finish even if you did have that much memory, which you don't and never will.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that malloc cannot possibly return a valid pointer to a block of memory that's is of the requested size due to memory constraints your system is faced with, thus malloc does what it normally does when it cannot allocate the desired memory -- it returns nullptr. ([malloc reference here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/))

The most relevant portion of the web-page linked is the following:

> Return Value:
>   On success, a pointer to the memory block allocated by the function.
>   The type of this pointer is always void*, which can be cast to the desired type of data pointer in order to be dereferenceable.
>   **If the function failed to allocate the requested block of memory, a null pointer is returned.**

The reason why you are getting an access violation error is due to the fact that you are trying to deference a pointer that is pointing to a null (hence invalid) location in memory.

In the future, I recommend you try to allocate more reasonably sized blocks of memory (For instance, 1kb, 1mb etc). If you wish to use an unsigned long long int you should perhaps look into creating something pertaining to math instead of memory manipulation.

**Addendum:**
If you want to get the max value for the type you should have done something like the following:
`std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max();` as noted by iBug, the number you input undergoes unsigned integer overflow. Integer overflow for unsigned integers is a defined behavior so the actual value of the magic value 18446744073709551616 is 0; you are malloc'ing 0 bytes.

The behavior for malloc'ing 0 bytes is the following (As per the c standard):

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that **the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object**.

**You still cannot deference the pointer returned or use it as an object.**

**As an aside:** `*(Array + i) = i;` is equivalent to `Array[i] = i;` or even `i[Array] = i;` :)

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned long long` is **non-negative 64-bit** integer, its highest possible value is 2<sup>64</sup>-1 = 1844674407370955161**5**. the compiler may not have known what you meant by 1844674407370955161**6** (value overflowed).

Also, 2<sup>64</sup> equals to 16 EB, or 16,777,216 TB. I don't know where such a huge storage is available, even if it's not RAM.

All `malloc` can do is finding that the requested size is *too huge* to allocate and return you a null pointer. Then when you're trying to access a null pointer, you get an "Access Violation" error.